# How to use python that comes from third party with Anaconda Spyder IDE

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a third party tool which gives Python packages and Python interpreter.

I want to use it through Anaconda Spyder IDE. The problem here is Spyder comes with default packages and Python. But i want to use third party interpreter and their settings in environment variable.

Even after settings the env variables provided by third party software in Spyder, It is still looking in Anaconda folder packages.

I got to here that to use a complete third party tool in Spyder, we need to clean up anaconda settings and everything. How to clean up everything.

How to remove the paths of ananconda folder in the spyder?